# Javascript remove items in array after a certain position

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, iterator

Lets assume you can never know what string will be passed to the browser, any combination of any characters of any length and I want to limit this to lets say.. 50 chars.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = "Hello this sentance was created in the browser!"
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        if(i == 50){

        }
    }
</script>
```

Eventually x will be something like:

```
var x = $('#textBit').html();
```

How will I remove everything in the array (string) after position 50, will I need a new for loop kinda like this (it may be wrong just thinking it up) pseudo code:

```
loop remainder string{
    do until end of array{
        remove item
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way of doing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `substr()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)). This will return the substring meeting you criteria, e.g., beginning at the start and having at most 50 characters:

```
var x = "Hello this sentance was created in the browser!"

var shortString = x.substr( 0, 50 );
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `string.substring(indexA[, indexB])` method:

> Returns a subset of a string between one index and another, or through
>   the end of the string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 3):

No:

```
if (x.length <= 50)
  return x;
else
   return x.substring(0, 50);
```

Comment: substring already does this check, so no need for checking it yourself.

Comment: Overhead of unnecessary function call ! ;D